# You are running `create-react-app` 5.0.0, which is behind the latest release (5.0.1)

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I got an error while creating a React application. How do I fix it?

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1586]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Olususi Victor>cd documents

C:\Users\Olususi Victor\Documents>cd react folder

C:\Users\Olususi Victor\Documents\React folder>npx create-react-app blog

You are running `create-react-app` 5.0.0, which is behind the latest release (5.0.1).

We no longer support global installation of Create React App.

Please remove any global installs with one of the following commands:
- npm uninstall -g create-react-app
- yarn global remove create-react-app

The latest instructions for creating a new app can be found here:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/


C:\Users\Olususi Victor\Documents\React folder>
```

[Image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOqQc.png)

Comment: Have you tried the commands that the error throws? I mean, it says to you exactly what to do: `uninstall create react app package and install it again`

Comment: Thanks, I have resolved it, i just uninstall and install the package again

Answer (score 95):

Run the following 3 commands sequentially:

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
npx clear-npx-cache
npm i create-react-app
npx create-react-app@latest my-app
```

Comment: you miss ```npm i create-react-app```

Comment: shouldnt it be `npm install -g create-react-app` ??, in case of gloabl installation

Comment: I only needed `npx clear-npx-cache` and then it stopped complaining. I didn't have `create-react-app` installed at all (not globally, not locally). npx was just being dumb.

Comment: Can you add an explanation on this solution to improve this answer?

Answer (score 10):

### MacOs 12.3.1 - Node v16.3.0 - NPM 7.15.1

I tried a lot of possible solutions, but the only one that worked for me was to **uninstall CRA globally AND locally**.

So, you have to run:

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app

npm uninstall create-react-app

npx clear-npx-cache
```

Comment: This one worked for me. After this command try the following - npm i create-react-app, npx create-react-app@latest my-app

Answer (score 7):

```
npx clear-npx-cache
npx create-react-app@latest app-name
```

Worked for me

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem, uninstalling `create-react-app` and installing the latest version solved the problem:

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
npx clear-npx-cache
npm cache clean --force
npm install -g create-react-app@latest
```

then you can create your react app with

```
npx create-react-app your-app-name
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you installed react globally? if yes, then remove it using

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

and then run your

```
npx create-react-app blog
```

if still you face the same issue than try creating a blog folder and inside that folder, run

```
npx create-react-app .
```

may be it will fix your issue.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
npm i create-react-app
npx create-react-app my-app
```

still not sure what happened thou

Answer (score 2):

Had this issue today (running node v16.13.1). Exact error message read:

```
You are running `create-react-app` 5.0.0, which is behind the latest release (5.0.1). We no longer support global installation of Create React App. Please remove any global installs with one of the following commands:

- npm uninstall -g create-react-app
- yarn global remove create-react-app

The latest instructions for creating a new app can be found here: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/
```

Solution that worked:

```
 1. npm uninstall -g create-react-app
 2. npm install -g create-react-app
 3. npm cache clean -f
 4. npx create-react-app my-app
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution that works for me:

1. `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`
2. `yarn uninstall -g create-react-app`
3. `npm i -g create-react-app`

Answer (score 2):

Try this: `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`. Then open: `C:\Users\Your_user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache` delete everything in the folders. Open: `C:\Users\Your_user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm` delete everything related to create-react-app.

Then finally: `npx create-react-app my-project` Worked for me. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this problem and by installing the package with yarn, everything works!
Even removing then reinstalling with npm, it didn't work. Here is my solution

```
yarn add create-react-app
create-react-app {app_name}
```

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered in this problem, I solved my issue by clearing the cache!

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still facing that
problem after uninstalling it globally and cleaning the cache, try to run;

```
npm uninstall create-react-app
```

as you might have a non-global installation

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with yarn? This works for me!

1. `yarn global remove create-react-app`
2. `yarn create react-app my-app`

Hope it works :)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
npx create-react-app@latest
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve mine by uninstalling Nodejs from my computer and then downloading the lastest one on my computer again.

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me.

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
npm uninstall create-react-app
npm cache clean --force
npm install create-react-app@latest
```

Answer (score 1):

if none of the answers worked for you, try adding this command after uninstalling the create-react-app package.

```
npm i create-react-app
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with this:

1. `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`
2. `npm install create-react-app@latest`

Answer (score 1):

1. `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`
2. `npm install -g create-react-app`
3. `npx clear-npx-cache`
4. `npx create-react-app@latest my-react-app`

...and u will be good to go.
go ahead with command like
`cd my-react-app`
`npm start`

Answer (score 1):

Actually I updated my script, I uninstalled react global and reinstalled but nothing changed. But yarn still works. I am still trying to solve problem but for a while, I will use

`yarn create react-app my-app`

Answer (score 1):

> npm uninstall -g create-react-app
>
> npx clear-npx-cache

Answer (score 0):

''' create-react-app projectName --template typescript '''

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app

npx create-react-app@latest blog
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck

Answer (score 0):

For me,

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

and

```
npx create-react-app@latest opus
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use this command

```
npx create-react-app@5.0.1 app-name
```