# "npm uninstall -g create-react-app" command is not working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

Trying to create a new react app. Getting this error:

You are running `create-react-app` 5.0.0, which is behind the latest release (5.0.1).

We no longer support global installation of Create React App.

Please remove any global installs with one of the following commands:

- npm uninstall -g create-react-app
- yarn global remove create-react-app

Ive ran the npm unistall command but when I try to run npm create-react-app I get the same error again. Tried to clear cache w/ npx clear-npx-cache also tried to update to 5.0.1 w/ npm install --save --save-exact react-scripts@5.0.1 still getting the same error.

Comment: What is the output when you run `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`?

Comment: Please we need more info to be able to help

Comment: you can check this out :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71852370/you-are-running-create-react-app-5-0-0-which-is-behind-the-latest-release-5

Answer (score 0):

What finally worked was deleting the create create-react-app directory from the terminal and creating a new project after that.

Answer (score 0):

npx clear-npx-cache

works for me.

And run npx create-react-app my-app