# After uninstalling create-react-app globally still getting 5.0.0 version of cra

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I was getting this error while

> npx create-react-app my-app

```
You are running `create-react-app` 5.0.0, which is 
behind the latest release (5.0.1).

We no longer support global installation of Create 
React App.

Please remove any global installs with one of the 
following commands:
- npm uninstall -g create-react-app
- yarn global remove create-react-app
```

So I uninstalled it using

> npm uninstall -g create-react-app

After I checked using

> npx create-react-app --version

It's still showing 5.0.0 and getting the same error while creating new app. I tried everything from [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71852370/you-are-running-create-react-app-5-0-0-which-is-behind-the-latest-release-5)

> npx version 8.3.1
> Node version v16.14.0
> manjaro os